# Zip Encoding Class Codeigniter with HTTPS

Tags: codeigniter, zip

I have this code:

```
public function descargar_todos_los_adjuntos_respuesta($codigo, $id) {
    $data = site_url() . "uploads/solicitud_fisica/" . $codigo . "/respuesta/";
    $this->zip->add_dir($data);
    $this->zip->download($codigo . '.zip');
}
```

When I use the `http` protocol it works perfect, but when I use the SSL protocol (`https`) the file download is corrupt.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's entirely unclear why you're adding an empty directory.  Something must be missing from the code you've shown as your ZIP would contain nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> *"When I use the `http` protocol it works perfect, but when I use the SSL protocol (`https`) the file download is corrupt."*

That's because you're inserting a full URL where [only a directory name is allowed](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html#CI_Zip::add_dir):

```
$data = site_url() . "uploads/solicitud_fisica/" . $codigo . "/respuesta/";
```

As per [the various examples in the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html), you would provide a server **path**, not a URL.  In the case of `add_dir()`, you would only provide a name of the new directory (or directories array), not a path or URL.

> `add_dir($directory)`
>
> **Parameters**:
>   `$directory` (mixed) – **Directory name string** or an array of multiple directories
>
> Permits you to add a directory. **Usually this method is unnecessary** since you can place your data into directories when using `$this->zip->add_data()`, but if you would like to create an empty directory you can do so:
>
> `$this->zip->add_dir('myfolder'); // Creates a directory called "myfolder"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i change my code but the problem still happen


 public function descargar_todos_los_adjuntos_respuesta($codigo, $id) { // Funcion que me permite descragar todos los adjuntos de una solicitud web
       `$data = "uploads/solicitud_fisica/" . $codigo . "/respuesta/";
        $this->zip->add_dir($data);
        $this->zip->download($codigo . '.zip');
    }`

Comment: @LucasFernandezRoldan, please re-read my answer and [refer to the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html#CI_Zip::add_dir).  You are still providing a path where you are only supposed to provide **a name** for the new directory.

Comment: Yes you are right i was doing something wrong, my final code is :`public function descargar_todos_los_adjuntos_solicitud($codigo) { // Funcion que me permite descragar todos los adjuntos de una solicitud web
        $datos = $this->Solicitud_fisica_model->buscar_solicitud_fisica_adjuntos($codigo)->result_array();
        foreach ($datos as $dato) {
            $data =  "uploads/solicitud_fisica/" . $codigo . "/solicitud/" . $dato ['solicitud_fisica_adjunto_archivo'];
            $this->zip->read_file($data); 
        }
        $this->zip->download($codigo . '.zip');
    }` thanks

Comment: @LucasFernandezRoldan, do not post all that code within comments. Edit your OP instead.